# Relative layout id is not getting on tablet in android

Tags: android-layout

I am making app for mobile ,7" tablet(600*1024) and 10" tablet(720*1280).  I created the following folders for layout and drawable.

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-land-hdpi
drawable-land-mdpi
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-port-mdpi
drawable-ldpi
drwable-mdpi


layout
layout-sw600dp(7")
layout-sw720dp(10")
layout-land
layout-sw600dp-land(7")
layout-sw720dp-land(10")
```

It is working fine on mobile but not working in tablets.It is giving null pointer exception for relative layout on fist screen of the app.It is not picking relative layout from XML while using tablet.I am testing on emulator.Can anybody help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem. `RelativeLayout` was id was null when I tested on tablet.

**Problem was:** By mistake I didn't added `RelativeLayout` in my layout `xml` corresponding to tablet, meaning large-layout.

Here in your case these (layout-sw600dp(7"), layout-sw720dp(10"), layout-sw600dp-land(7"), layout-sw720dp-land(10")) are folders related to large screens.

To resolve the issue I added `RelativeLayout` in corresponding `xml` file in large layout folders.

And it stopped throwing `NPE` for `RelativeLayout` when I tested it again for tablets.